# PyCharm 2018.2.4 and Anaconda 5.3.0

Tags: numpy, pycharm, anaconda

Mine is Anaconda 5.3.0

When I run .py in PyCharm 2018.2.4, why it shows that:

```
ImportError: 
DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

ImportError: 
Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.

Original error was: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

It seems that PyCharm 2018.2.4 cannot import numpy??

Does anyone see this problem too? How to fix it? Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you have your heart set on using Anaconda, because I use pip to install all of my packages and I haven't had any issues with PyCharm, you might want to try that.

Comment: Wouldn't imagine that to be PyCharm specific; what happens if you open an interpreter in your conda environment and import numpy from there?

Comment: Do you have the full Anaconda (and therefore numpy was already installed along with it)? Or did you install it manually? Also, is yout pycharm project using a virtual environment or is it set to use the global anaconda env? If it is using a virtual environment, then it would be crucial to know what happens outside of pycharm like fuglede asked

Comment: I solved it by conda uninstall numpy, pip uninstall numpy and pip install numpy... Never going to use conda again.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the Python interpreter path on PyCharm to the Anaconda one (something like ~/anaconda3/bin/python).

Todo do so, open the Settings dialog >> Project: [ProjName] in the left panel >> Project Interpreter. Now you can add to the list paths to local Python interpreters, or virtual environments in the project folder or in a folder specified in the WORKON_HOME.

More instructions [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm-edu/configuring-python-interpreter-for-a-project.html) and [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm-edu/configuring-available-python-interpreters.html).

Comment: I recommend pasting the relevant information from your link so that in case the page ever disappears, future users with the same problem can still access your info.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I have useful information if not the solution.

I too received the error using python to import numpy from the windows command prompt. Then I realized I could succeed if I used the Anaconda prompt. Curious about the difference, I exited python and examined the PATH environment variable. As I had hoped, it contained Anaconda references that did not exist in the Windows PATH. At the command prompt I typed:  path > p.txt   and hit enter to create a file since the string was so long. When I opened the file in notepad I copied the Anaconda references to the clipboard (C:\Users\laptop\Anaconda3;C:\Users\laptop\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\Users\laptop\Anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;C:\Users\laptop\Anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\Users\laptop\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Users\laptop\Anaconda3\bin;) then used the Advanced Settings under the System Control Panel to Edit the Environment Variable and paste it on the beginning of PATH. The problem seems to have gone away, both in the Windows shell and in Pycharm.

Answer (score 0):

First, try to delete .git file from project folder and re-enable vcs. Then uninstall numpy by:

```
pip3 uninstall numpy
```

After that, go to pycharm and open `File > settings > Project Intepreter` get the python location url ex: `usr/bin/python3`. Copy that path and open terminal and type: 
`usr/bin/python3 install numpy`. Wait for pycharm indexing and try to run project again

Comment: What is the reasoning behind deleting all git folders? Also why do you propose doing `pip3 uninstall numpy`? Op said he uses Anaconda, so the `numpy` was probably installed using conda/was shipped with Anaconda

Comment: .git may be conflicting with packages, so deleting them will show if it is related to git or not. Reinstalling the numpy will refresh the package

Comment: ".git may be conflicting with packages" I have never heard this and cannot imagine how that would even be possible. Could you elaborate how that is?

Comment: "Reinstalling the numpy will refresh the package" - I agree that reinstalling might be a good idea, but pip is probably not the best option to uninstall and reinstall considering OP is using Anaconda that probably installed `numpy` using `conda`. I also think you probably meant `usr/bin/python3 -m pip install numpy`

Comment: removing .git is one option another way of doing that is to clean caches of git. If u can manage to remove that u can do that. But the point is that it could be regarding virtual env that you might created inside working path

Comment: So, numpy inside that env could be added in git as well. I suppose

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's an issue with PyCharm. 
I got Anaconda 5.3 today and use PyCharm Pro 2018.2.4. Unfortunately, I got the same error as you do. However, if you go to powershell (if you are on Windows like me), type in python and import numpy you still got the same error. 
Not sure why yet but uninstall & reinstall didn't help (and tbh I don't get why this might help in any sense though).

So my current solution is:

Roll back to Anaconda 5.2 with Python 3.6 and everything gets back to working.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21033291)

Comment: @Martin You are right and I'm sorry. I had a workaround (not optimal but working for me) and just edited it.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same thing, pychrm 2018.2 &  Anaconda3 (64-bit) 5.3  on win10

I think the issue is about Anaconda, I have uninstalled  the Anaconda 5.3 and installed Anaconda 5.2, then everything is ok